# How do I write Gremlin queries for following patterns?

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop-blueprint

I have some miniature Gremlin directed graphs, in which each vertex has two properties "type" and "text". The values for "text" property are just English text while the "type" property can a have a value selected from this set :

```
NP, PP, VP, ADVP, ADJP, SBAR, PRT, INTJ, O
```

All edges in those graphs have same label : "next".

I want to be able to select the graphs which have following patterns of nodes:

```
1) [text=","] --> type="VP" --> type="ADVP" --> type="NP"
2) type="NP" --> [text="," Upto 3 nodes with any text and type text=","] --> type="VP" --> [text=":" OR "that"]
```

The pattern element in brackets means that it is optional.

So, for first pattern, I need to select the graphs which have a node with text "," optionally, followed by a node with type "VP", followed by "ADVP", followed "NP".

For second pattern, I need to select the graphs which have a node type "NP", followed by an optional sequence of nodes starting with a node with text "," then upto 3 nodes with any text and type and then a node with text ",". This optional sequence is then followed by a node of type "VP" and finally a node with text ":" or "that".

Two sample graphs that would match with first pattern are :

[image: Pattern 1]

Following are sample graphs that would match with second pattern:
[image]

I understand basic Gremlin traversals but I am not sure about how to handle optional elements of the pattern above.

Is there any way to write queries for such patterns in Gremlin? If not, can you suggest a non-Gremlin based approach to create such graphs and querying them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do pattern matching in Gremlin as of TinkerPop 3.0.  You would use [Match Step](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-incubating/#match-step) to accomplish your task.  I've written the Gremlin to do so as an example for your first requirement.  Perhaps that will inspire you to develop the traversal for your second requirement.

I generated some data as follows:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> v1=g.addV(id, 1, "type", "o", "text", ",").next()
==>v[1]
gremlin> v2=g.withSideEffect('x',v1).addV(id, 2, "type", "vp", "text", "a").addInE('next','x').inV().next()
==>v[2]
gremlin> v3=g.withSideEffect('x',v2).addV(id, 3, "type", "advp", "text", "b").addInE('next','x').inV().next()
==>v[3]
gremlin> g.withSideEffect('x',v3).addV(id, 4, "type", "np", "text", "c").addInE('next','x').inV().next()
==>v[4]
gremlin> 
gremlin> v5=g.addV(id, 5, "type", "vp", "text", "a").next()
==>v[5]
gremlin> v6=g.withSideEffect('x',v5).addV(id, 6, "type", "advp", "text", "b").addInE('next','x').inV().next()
==>v[6]
gremlin> g.withSideEffect('x',v6).addV(id, 7, "type", "np", "text", "c").addInE('next','x').inV().next()
==>v[7]
gremlin> 
gremlin> v8=g.addV(id, 8, "type", "vp", "text", "a").next()
==>v[8]
gremlin> v9=g.withSideEffect('x',v8).addV(id, 9, "type", "o", "text", ",").addInE('next','x').inV().next()
==>v[9]
gremlin> g.withSideEffect('x',v9).addV(id, 10, "type", "np", "text", "c").addInE('next','x').inV().next()
==>v[10]
```

Then for the matching traversal:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('type','vp').match(__.as('vp').coalesce(__().in().has('text',','),constant("optional")).as('o'),
gremlin>                              __.as('vp').out().has('type','advp').as('advp'),
gremlin>                              __.as('advp').out().has('type','np').as('np')).select('o','vp','advp','np')
==>[o:v[1], vp:v[2], advp:v[3], np:v[4]]
==>[o:optional, vp:v[5], advp:v[6], np:v[7]]
```